# PL/SQL Mac compiler or Mac OS X compatible softwares

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation

How can I run PL/SQL in Mac OS X Lion. I couldn't find any compatible application for mac to run PL/SQL. Please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/features/oracle_editor.html) in the past for MSSQL/MySql/Postgres connectivity, but not for Oracle.  It's a good product for the price (if you consider how much Toad costs, but is not as feature rich)

Comment: Ok thank u. I couldn't find any procedure to load PL/SQL in `RAZORSQL` & I'm running on trail version.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I couldn't find any procedure to load PL/SQL" ?

Comment: I'm sorry finally I found how to run PL/SQL.